# xquery function to remove new line from xml element

Tags: xml, function, xquery, newline, osb

**when i tried to assign a large string value to element 'x' using xquery mapping it is creating a new line .instead i want it with out a new line .
**

`<ABC>
<X>
86E95A47AD2037B203521BBE7DAC71A11FE2DBD539D21CF66A9024B30505090F52F687F5BB299BD21A25E2ED01079A009B25FCFB7DCCBAF1DAB16E78B8CE179A922B94957989DBF531F967E46ACFB1B474A6F4CFD6AFB8C61D5BBB62346C502F837A68A15CD12ED90C03371EFB8C9922FB6B7860
</X>
<Y>70406352</Y>
</ABC>`

**Requirement**

`<ABC>
<X>86E95A47AD2037B203521BBE7DAC71A11FE2DBD539D21CF66A9024B30505090F52F687F5BB299BD21A25E2ED01079A009B25FCFB7DCCBAF1DAB16E78B8CE179A922B94957989DBF531F967E46ACFB1B474A6F4CFD6AFB8C61D5BBB62346C502F837A68A15CD12ED90C03371EFB8C9922FB6B7860</X>
<Y>70406352</Y>
</ABC>`

Comment: You need to share what you already tried to do, i.e. actual XQuery. Also, it could be just human eye issues. XQuery serialization controls XQuery output rules.

Answer (score 0):

You could run it through a recursive typeswitch function, with special processing for the `X` element to `normalize-space()` on the `text()` (or any other more specific replacement of leading carriage returns:

Targeting specifically the `X` element and it's `text()`:

```
declare function local:filter($nodes){
  for $node in $nodes 
  return
    typeswitch ($node)
      case text() return $node
      case attribute() return $node
      case comment() return $node
      case processing-instruction() return $node
      case element (X) return element {name($node)} {( $node/@*, $node/node() except $node/text(), $node/text()/normalize-space())}
      default return element {name($node)} {($node/@*, local:filter($node/node()))}
};
```

Or more generically, `normalize-space()` for all `text()` nodes:

```
declare function local:filter($nodes){
  for $node in $nodes 
  return
    typeswitch ($node)
      case text() return normalize-space($node)
      case attribute() return $node
      case comment() return $node
      case processing-instruction() return $node
      default return element {name($node)} {($node/@*, local:filter($node/node()))}
};
```

Comment: Hello sir,I tried the same and it is working with small strings (ex:Y element ),but for X with large string value it is not working.